# Cannot assign "{'id': 31}": "Model.table_ABC" must be a "ABC" instance

Tags: django

I double checked if the id 31 exists, where `some_id` here is 31, where id is a pk. It does exist under ABC model and there is data.

I don't see how this is incorrect?
I've also tried `ABC.objects.filter(id=some_id)`, also tried just setting `abc=31`, which doesn't make sense but wanted to try, also tried `.get(pk=some_id)`

ABC is a foreign key to Model.

```
a_id = ABC.objects.get(id=some_id)
person_abc= Model(user=request.user, abc=a_id)
form = ModelForm(request.POST, instance=person_abc)
```

Comment: That's not coming from this code. Please show the full traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you're right! it's not from this code. It was coming from `forms.py`